# SSRS: Performance concerned with replace

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to replace text in a field in an SSRS report with a lot of data. Are there any performance concerns between the following?

```
=iif(Fields!Field1.Value="Word 1", "Word 2", Fields!Field1.Value)
```

...and...

```
=Replace(Fields!thisItem.Value, "Word 1","Word 2")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not enough to worry about in most cases

However, they are different expressions which is more important

- One is a check for a *specific* value followed by substitution
- The other scans a string for *all* occurrences of "Word 1"